# mod_rewrite rule for anchors

Tags: mod-rewrite, anchor

I want to rewrite a **url** to a **url with anchors**

```
from "topic/14/599" to "topic.php?id=14#599"
```

this is my current rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /topic.php?id=$1#$2 [NE,L,R]
```

this works fine, but the rewritten rule is in the adressbar !
so the browser's addressbar changes from "topic/14/599" to "topic.php?id=14#599"

I would prefer to keep the "simplified" version in the addressbar, the rewriterule however doesn't work without the L,R-flags, I just can't get it to work. 
(if I just rewrite topic/14 to topic.php?id=14 without any flags it works just fine)

Update:

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ topic.php?id=$1&a=$2 [NE]
```

now works! the addressbar looks to the user like: mydomain.com/topic/14/599
and internally it is redirected to topic.php?id=14&a=599 and once the page is loaded, javascript jumps to the element with id=599!

Answer (score 2):

Since anchors are processed on the client side, there's no way to rewrite to an anchor "silently" like you're trying to do -- the anchor has to be in the user-visible URL at some point. You could rewrite `topic/14/244` to `topic/14#244` as a redirect and rewrite `topic/14` internally to `topic.php?id=14`, but you can't do both in a single step.

Comment: thanks! I thought I could do everything with mod_rewrite ;) I'll redirect now to topic.php?id=1&a=32 and then use javascript to set the focus to the anchor! (and the addressbar looks like I wanted to: topic/1/32)